# Where can I find QGIS cartogram plug-in?

Tags: qgis, cartogram

Can anyone point me in the right direction of the cartogram plugin please? I've had a look on the net but can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: How did you look on the Net? The first hit in Googling "QGIS Cartogram" takes me to @Underdark's [blog](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/creating-cartograms-with-qgis-cartogram-creator/) and the second sentence locates the plugin!

Answer (score 6):

<del>At the bottom of [Carson Farmer's plugin repository page](http://www.ftools.ca/cfarmerQgisRepo.xml)</del>

Carsen Farmer recently blogged that he took down [his ftools page](http://www.carsonfarmer.com/2013/10/ftools-is-no-more/), with an explanation why. This answer originally linked to that page. [His blog entry](http://www.carsonfarmer.com/2013/10/ftools-is-no-more/) notes that the Cartogram plugin has not yet been integrated/ported into QGIS 2.0, so he offers a link to the Cartogram code [on his site](http://www.carsonfarmer.com/uploads/cartogram.zip) and [on github](https://github.com/cfarmer/cartogram-plugin).

---

**LATE UPDATE**

The plugin is now in the official QGIS plugin repo: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cartogram/ , as well as on Github: https://github.com/informeren/qgis-cartogram

Comment: Carson Fermer's page only uses a point file, isn't described as using a polygon file

Comment: Thats just an error in the description. See Underdarks blogpost to view how it works with polygons.